# Read complex JSON data in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, angular7

Below is JSON Data:

```
var Dataset = [
      {
        "studentname": "Rockey",
        "age": 13,
        "average": 8.2,
        "exam": [{"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"},
         {"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"},
         {"Status": "Fail", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"}]
      },
      {
        "name": "Jony",
        "age": 13,
        "average": 8.2,
        "exam": [{"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"},
        {"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"},
         {"Status": "Fail", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"}]
      },
      {
        "name": "Rock",
        "age": 13,
        "average": 8.2,
        "exam": [{"Status": "Fail", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"},
        {"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"},
         {"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "studentId": "KG19932"}]
      },
       [{"studentname": "Rockey", "attempt": "10"},
       {"studentname": "Jony", "attempt": "20"},
       {"studentname": "Rock", "attempt": "15"}]
    ]
```

I want to Print output :

""""""{{studentname}}'s  score is **{{statusFailcount/TotalCount }}** out of  {{attempt}}th attempt in this year."""""""

so basically I stuck to print {{statusFailcount/TotalCount }} so lets understand what is statusFailcount and TotalCount. If you see in first exam array status as pass count is  **two** and status as **Fail** count is only one and total count of status in exam array is **three**(pass(two)+Fail(one)).
and remaining parameters same as available in JSON like studentname and attempt.

Below is logic I have implemented for to get name of student and its attempt:

```
dataSet[dataSet.length - 1].forEach(item => {
                        this.tempArray.push({ Totalattempt: item.attempt, studentData: item.studentname });
                       });
```

logic to find the totalStatusCount is :

```
dataSet.forEach(x=>{
                        this.tempArrayFailCount.push({Totalcount:x.values.length})

                });
```

Now only problem i left with to calculate the count of **pass** in status array

if you see for first case output should be
""""""""Rockey's score is **2/3** out of 10th attempt in this year.""""""""" and am struggling to find the value of 2.

Can someone guide me on this??

Comment: Can you share your code and the errors you're getting?

Comment: You want to do `{{statusFailcount}}/{{TotalCount}}`, otherwise you'll evaluate the division

Comment: @shampooSham if you see second  last line of my question i have given one example.  i just want to display count of pass and from total status count.and it is not fixed. and  I don't want to evaluate division just show the count from total count .

Comment: Ok. Btw, does your JSON really look like that? Do you have "studentname" for the first student (Rockey) and "name" for the others? Do you have an array with the attempts at the end of the array?

Comment: @CameronLittle I have updated the question with more explanation